# login to a site using python and opening the login site in the browser

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication

I am learning how to login a website using python through this [site](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/278635/python-site-login), and applying it to my site. So that I can open the webpage without any login requirements. It does not show any errors, but I can't accomplish what I want. May the way I am doing is not the way to do it, then please answer how to achieve it. What I want is to login through the credentials I gave and then open up the browser. However when the page loads, its still not logged in. Hope what I meant was clear. Please ask me if my question is not cleared. Will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I modified a little bit to accomplish the goal:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
import webbrowser
#cookie storage
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
#create an opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
#Add useragent, sites don't like to interact programs.
opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0'))
opener.addheaders.append( ('Referer', 'http://somesite.com/adminpanel/index.php') )
#encode the login data. This will vary from site to site.
#View the sites source code
#Example###############################################
#<form id='loginform' method='post' action='index.php'>
#<div style="text-align: center;">
#Username<br />
#<input type='text' name='admin_userid' class='textbox' style='width:100px' /><br />
#Password<br />
#<input type='password' name='admin_password' class='textbox' style='width:100px' /><br />
#<input type='checkbox' name='remember_me' value='y' />Remember Me<br /><br />
#<input type='submit' name='login' value='Login' class='button' /><br />
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'admin_userid' : 'admin',
                               'admin_password' : 'test',
                               'login' : 'Login'
                               })
resp = opener.open('http://somesite.com/adminpanel/index.php', login_data)
#you are now logged in and can access "members only" content.
#when your all done be sure to close it

webbrowser.open('http://somesite.com/adminpanel/index.php')

resp.close()
```

Comment: You have logged in through the connection made by your python script, not through the (new) connection your webbrowser opens...

Answer (score 0):

By this you are opening the url, but where is the cookie? I mean you are missing cookie, that's why you are always seeing the login page on your browser.

```
webbrowser.open('http://somesite.com/adminpanel/index.php')
```

You can read the html from the resp and save into a html and, and then load the html file on browser if you want.

```
for html in resp:
    print html
```

Comment: If I save the html and then load it again, wont it ask for authentication again?

Comment: If you display the saved html, its more or less a static page. So it will not ask for anything. I don't know for which purpose you are using this. But best approach will be Save the cookie(pointing cookie-jar to a file) after login. And next time when you are browsing the page, just use the saved session cookie(pointing the file to your cookie-jar) with it, and it will not show you the login for(until the cookie doesn't expire).

Answer (score 0):

look here what you did was establish a connection to the site using your script, but not with your browser, I recommend that you head to http://docs.seleniumhq.org/